# Проблема удаления объекта через указатель базового класса

Tags: c++

Я сразу перейду к примеру:

```
class B {
    int k{};
   //... НЕТ виртального деструктора
};

class D : public B {
    int n{1};
    //...
};
void foo(B* pb)
{
    //...
    pb = new D;
    //...
    delete pb;
}
```

Может ли возникать проблема в функции? Если может, то почему или что говорится в стандарте по этому поводу(имеется ввиду для простых типов)?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стандарт не делает разницы между простыми и сложными типами. Удаление наследника через указатель на родителя без виртуального деструктора - всегда неопределенное поведение.

> #### [`[expr.delete]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3)
>
> In a single-object delete expression, if the static type of the object to be deleted is not similar ([conv.qual]) to its dynamic type and the selected deallocation function (see below) is not a destroying operator delete, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

Вольный перевод: если вызвать `delete` на указателе типа `A *`, который на самом деле указывает на объект типа `B`, то `B` должен быть наследником `A`, и у `A` должен быть виртуальный деструктор, иначе поведение не определено.

---

На практике да, если `B` не добавляет новых полей с непустыми деструкторами, то ничего не должно сломаться.

Но можно словить краш, если экземпляр родителя находится не в самом начале потомка, а где-то в середине (потому что перед ним - другой родитель, или указатель на виртуальную таблицу). Из-за этого в функцию, освобождающую память (`operator delete()`) приходит не тот адрес.

```
struct A {int x;};
struct C : A {virtual void foo() {}};

int main()
{
    A *a = new C;
    delete a;
}
```

```
struct A {int x;};
struct B {int y;};
struct C : A, B {};

int main()
{
    B *b = new C;
    delete b;
}
```

```
struct A {int x;};
struct C : virtual A {};

int main()
{
    A *a = new C;
    delete a;
}
```

Comment: как это получается что со случаем виртуального наследования указатель на родитедя указывает в середину?? в какую середину? Там же всего 2 класса в иерархии...

Comment: "На практике да, если B не добавляет новых полей с непустыми деструкторами, то ничего не должно сломаться". В принципе эта часть ответа  более интересует.  Так не должно или точно никакого UB не будет в таком случаи?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan По стандарту UB будет в любом случае.

Comment: @ampawd Перед ним указатель на виртуальную таблицу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо, тут у нас с сыном был спор по этому поводу:):)